# Cómo puedo hacer una llamada desde una Activity con el dispositivo bloqueado

Tags: java, android, activity

Estoy trabajando en una app que realice llamadas programadas a determinadas horas, el problema que tengo es que cuando el dispositivo esta bloqueado no realiza las llamadas.
La forma en la que realizo las llamadas es con un activity:

**Edit: Utilizo alarmManager para programar las llamadas, agrego el código de la Clase

```
public class AlarmReceiver_SendOn extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    static MainActivity instance = MainActivity.getInst();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        final String number = intent.getStringExtra("PhoneNumber");

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    return;
        context.startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Me gustaría que las llamadas se realizaran aun con el dispositivo bloqueado

Comment: Te recomendaría que mirares el WorkManager de Android. https://www.google.com/search?client=opera-gx&q=workmanager&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8. La forma que estás usando tu usa el contexto, si la activity no está en primer plano, el contexto no existe, ergo no se pueden hacer llamadas. Necesitarías programar una servicio (Service, AlarmManager, o el WorkManager que te he sugerido, por ejemplo) para poder realizar tareas en segundo plano, aún sin la activity en primer plano.

Comment: Entiendo, lo que provoca el conflicto. Estoy utilizando AlarmManager y cuando este es llamado, a la hora que programe, ejecuta la llamada como en el código compartido, es posible trabajar sobre lo que tengo ?

Answer (score 0):

podrías probar de lanzarlo en un servicio en segundo plano y por otro hilo de ejecuciòn. 
Porque creo que la activity se detiene cuando se bloquea el dispositivo.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar la clase WorkManager para programar tus tareas. Te dejo un ejemplo.

build.gradle // agregar las dependencias

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.4"
```

manifest.xml // Se recomienda Sobreescribir el inicializador del work manager

```
<application>

    .....

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="false"/>

</application>
```

Application // Tenemos que sobreescribir la configuración

```
class FamApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider{

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() = Configuration.Builder()
.setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
.build();

}
```

MyWork // en esta clase va tu lógica que quieres ejecutar periodicamente

```
class MyWorker(private val context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters ) : Worker(context, workerParameters) {
override fun doWork(): Result {
    val phone = "+34666777888"
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null))
    intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    context.startActivity(intent)

    return Result.success()
}

}
```

Finalmente ejecutamos y configuramos nuestro work manager

```
    val constraints = Constraints.Builder().build()
//constraints te permite agregarle reglas a tu workmanager
        val work = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()
        // Creamos un workmanager periódico para trabajar y agregamos la frecuencia y la unidad( para este ejemplo cada minuto)
        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this)
        workManager.enqueue(work)
```

He agregado un ejemplo básico, para configurar el work manager con más parámetros te dejo algunos enlaces donde puedes personalizarlo para tus necesidades. Pero tu caso de uso te recomiendo que utilices workmanager.

Referencias

- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-adv-workmanager/#2
- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics
- https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/android/trabajador-asincrono-en-android-workmanager/838652905/
- https://www.belatrixsf.com/blog/tareas-android-workmanager

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Buenas, actualmente estoy utilizando alarmManager para ejecutar las llamadas a ciertas horas, es posible seguir por ese camino ?

Comment: Hola! Por supuesto :) , también puedes utilizar el AlarmManager, pero recuerda manejarlo bien. Te dejo la documenctación para que lo manejes de la manera correcta [ https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms].